# Way to handle refresh token

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am working on login feature and have problem when refresh token.

When token expire making request to refresh token, remove the old token, and save the new token to AsyncStorage.

After login successfully have to function A and B. The function A is using the new token to make its request. the function B say that it need to refresh the token so make request to refresh token ( the request make successfully, token being refresh) but The token that request A is using now `invalid`  - I think it happens due to asynchronous

This is my code that use to refresh token:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    return response;
  },
  async function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === CODE_TOKEN_EXPIRED) {
      try {
        const token = await authenticationService.getRefreshToken();
        const response = await authenticationService.refreshToken(token);
        await authenticationService.removeToken();
        await authenticationService.storeToken(response.data.params.access_token);
        await authenticationService.storeRefreshToken(response.data.params.refresh_token);
        error.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.params.access_token;
        error.response.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.params.access_token;
        return axiosInstance(error.config);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(2, err);
        await authenticationService.removeToken();
        navigationService.navigate('LoginForm');
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Anyone know how to handle which asynchronous call for refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

First would be for you to check if you are changing token to the correct axios instance. It is necessary to change Authorization header on error.response config as you did, but also for main axios instance (if you have one) like so: `axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + access_token;`

If it is multiple parallel requests going on that could possibly need to be postponed after token is refreshed issue and answer gets complex, but check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Godofbrowser/bf118322301af3fc334437c683887c5f) with full refresh logic with axios.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same scenario in fetch API. you can also do this same in axios API. Try this to avoid interceptor concept.

**Api.ts**

```
export const api = ({ method, url, body, isProtected = true }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const payload = {
      method,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    if (body !== null) {
      (payload as any).body = JSON.stringify(body);
    }

        /**
        * "isProtected" is used for API call without authToken
        */

    if (isProtected) {
      AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN).then(accessKey => {
        (payload.headers as any).Authorization = `Bearer ${accessKey}`;
        fetch(url, payload)
          .then((response: any) => {

                        /*
                        * 419 status denotes the timeout of authToken
                        */

            if (response.status == 419) {
              // refresh token
              AsyncStorage.getItem(REFRESH_TOKEN).then(refreshKey => {

                const payloadRef = {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + refreshKey
                  }
                };
                                /*
                                * This call refresh the authToken using refreshing call to renew the authToken
                                */
                fetch(URL.baseUrl + "/refresh", payloadRef)
                  .then((response: any) => response.json())
                  .then(response => {

                                        /*
                                        * if refresh token expired. redirect to login page
                                        */

                    if (response.status !== codes.SUCCESS) {
                      if (!User.sessionOver) {
                        User.sessionOver = true;
                        Alert.alert(
                          'Alert',
                          'Session Timeout',
                          [
                            {
                              text: 'Get back to Login',
                              onPress: () => {
                                // get to Login page
                              }
                            }
                          ],
                          { cancelable: false }
                        );
                      }
                    } else if (response.status == codes.SUCCESS) {

                                            /*
                                            * If refresh token got refreshed and set it as authToken and retry the api call.
                                            */

                      AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.payload.access_key).then(() => {
                        (payload.headers as any).Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.payload.access_key;
                        fetch(url, payload)
                          .then(response => response.json())
                          .then(response => {
                            if (response.status == codes.SUCCESS) {
                              resolve(response);
                            }
                          })
                          .catch(error => {
                            reject(error);
                          });
                      });
                    }
                  });
              });
            } else {
              resolve(response.json());
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    } else {
      fetch(url, payload)
        .then((response: any) => {
          response = response.json();
          resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    }
  });
};
```

**MovieService.ts**

```
import { api } from '../services/api';
import { URL } from '../config/UrlConfig';

const getMovies = () => {
  const method = 'GET';
  const url = URL.baseUrl + '/v1/top/movies';
  const body = null;
  const isProtected = true;
  return api({ method, url, body, isProtected });
};

export { getMovies };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will helps -  https://gist.github.com/ModPhoenix/f1070f1696faeae52edf6ee616d0c1eb

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { settings } from "../settings";
import { authAPI } from ".";

const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: settings.apiV1,
});

request.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    // Get token and add it to header "Authorization"
    const token = authAPI.getAccessToken();
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = token;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

let loop = 0;
let isRefreshing = false;
let subscribers = [];

function subscribeTokenRefresh(cb) {
  subscribers.push(cb);
}

function onRrefreshed(token) {
  subscribers.map((cb) => cb(token));
}

request.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (err) => {
  const {
    config,
    response: { status },
  } = err;
  const originalRequest = config;

  if (status === 401 && loop < 1) {
    loop++;
    if (!isRefreshing) {
      isRefreshing = true;
      authAPI.refreshToken().then((respaonse) => {
        const { data } = respaonse;
        isRefreshing = false;
        onRrefreshed(data.access_token);
        authAPI.setAccessToken(data.access_token);
        authAPI.setRefreshToken(data.refresh_token);
        subscribers = [];
      });
    }

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      subscribeTokenRefresh((token) => {
        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        resolve(axios(originalRequest));
      });
    });
  }
  return Promise.reject(err);
});

export default request;
```